# add remaining colors to the array list by looking at the enum

Tags: java, list, enums

I have a List called `colorList` which can have either all Colors enum or part of it.

```
public enum Colors {
    RED, BLUE, PINK;        

    private String pickColor(DataKey dataKey) {
        List<Colors> colorsList = dataKey.getColors();
        // add at the end of colorsList
    }
}
```

- If `colorList` only has one color in it, then remaining two colors I need to add from Colors enum at the end of `colorsList`.
- If `colorList` only has two color in it, then last color I need to add from Colors enum at the end of `colorsList`.
- If `colorList` has all three colors, then I don't need to add anything to `colorsList`.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by building a `List` of the available colors, remove the `List` of starting colors from it and then add the remaining colors to the starting list, for example...

```
List<Colors> startColors = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new Colors[]{Colors.RED, Colors.PINK}));
List<Colors> availableColors = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(Colors.values()));
availableColors.removeAll(startColors);
startColors.addAll(availableColors);

System.out.println(startColors);
```

which outputs...

```
[RED, PINK, BLUE]
```

If I change the `startColors` to be...

```
List<Colors> startColors = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new Colors[]{Colors.PINK}));
```

it outputs...

```
[PINK, RED, BLUE]
```

You could add in a check to see if the `startColors` has the same number of elements as the `availableList` and if, after you remove the `startColors` from the `availableList` if there are any colors remaining which might improve the performance

*ps* I had thought about using `Set`, but sets are generally unordered :P

Comment: I didn't understand your second last para comment. Could you add that just to make myself clear. And how will it improve performance?

Comment: Think about this, if the `startColors` has 3 elements, you could assume that it has all the available colors (but since it's not a `Set`, it might contain three instances of `PINK`), so when you `removeAll` from availableColors if it has no elements left, why call `addAll`?